# Is there an intuitive reason why $J_0$ should be the only Bessel function that behaves different than its kind at 0?

Tags: intuition, bessel-functions

I'm staring at the Bessel functions, and I'm trying to figure out exactly why $J_0$ should behave differently than $J_{1^+}$: at zero, only $J_0(0)=1$, and $J_{n\geq1}(0)=0$.

[image: j_n]

Even all of $Y_n$ behave in the same singular way:

[image: y_n]

It strikes me as odd that one element in an infinite series would exhibit unique behavior at 0. It seems like there should be an explanation for the behavior of $J_0$ other than "it solves the equation," but I'm not sure what that might be.

Is there one?

Comment: Do you mean why $J_0$ is nonzero at zero while the others are zero? In fact there *is* a pattern, and it has to do with the Maclaurin series: $J_n$ vanishes to order $n$ at $x=0$.

Comment: @Ian Whoops, I asked a question and then... forgot to include my question. Edited a wee bit.

Comment: One way to think about it: for integer $n>0$, a solution to Bessel's equation either vanishes at $x=0$ (if it is a multiple of $J_n$) or is unbounded there (if it has a contribution from $Y_n$). You can see this by playing around with power series analysis.

Comment: In case it's not clear from Ian's comment about zeros of order $n$, the unifying fact here is that $J_n(x)\sim x^n$ at the origin.

Comment: Oh, yikes. That's way simpler than I thought it would be. Yeah, peeking at the Maclaurin series really helps.

Comment: Bessel functions are funny things and it can be difficult to gain intuition, but the series is a pretty solid start for a lot of things.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to derive it is from the representation of $J_n(x)$ as  Fourier series coefficients:
$$ J_n(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-int} e^{ix \sin(t)}\; dt $$

So $$J_n(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-int}\; dt $$
which of course is $0 $ for integers $n \ne 0$ and $1$ for $n=0$.